# AOP with Spring 3 using Annotations

Tags: java, spring, aspect

I am trying to get Aspect working with Spring 3 and annotations.

```
@Aspect
public class AttributeAspect {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.mak.selective.annotation.Attribute)")
  public void process(){
    System.out.println("Inside Process ....");
  }

  @Around("process()")
  public void processAttribute(){
    System.out.println("Inside Actual Aspect ..");
  }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mak.selective.annotation.*" />
<bean name="attribute" class="com.mak.selective.annotation.AttributeAspect"/>
</beans>
```

MY Test to test the Aspect:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/springcontext/*.xml")
public class AttributeTest {

@Attribute(tableName = "firstTable", columnName = "New Column")
private void getAttribute() {
    System.out.println("Inside Attribute call...");
}

@Test
public void testAttributeAspect() {
    getAttribute();
}
```

}

With this code i can only see "Inside Attribute call..." but nothing from Aspect.
Please guide.

> > > > > Got this working by making a new Object (Component) and injected to the Junit test class.

Answer (score 1):

Good to see that you got it working from XML, but you could have also done it from annotations.

The issue is that the `@Aspect` annotation is not a Spring stereotype, so the scanner is not registering the aspect as a Spring Bean.  Just add either `@Service` or `@Component` above or below `@Aspect` and it will be registered.

Also, either directly name the bean (e.g., `@Service("myNamedService")`) or have it implement an interface (e.g., `public class AttributeAspect implements IAspect {`), as per standard Spring design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use real AspectJ if you want to intercept invocations of methods within the same bean form where it is invoked. (What you have done, should work if the method testAttributeAspect() is located in an other bean.)

---

How to do real AspectJ?

> Using the AspectJ compiler and weaver enables use of the full AspectJ language, and is discussed in Section 7.8, “Using AspectJ with Spring applications”.

@See [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-using-aspectj)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Firstly, when you do around advice you need to write the advice method like this:

```
@Around(...)
public void aroundAdviceMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    try {
        System.out.println("before...");
        pjp.proceed();
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("After...");
    }
}
```

But also (and this at least applies when you're using proxies, not entirely sure in your case), the method you're putting advice on needs to be public (yours isn't), spring managed (via @Component or otherwise) and called external from the class so the proxy can take effect (also not the case in your example). So you need something like this:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Attribute
    public void someMethodCall() {
        System.out.println("In method call");
    }
}

public class SomeUnitTest {
    @Autowired SomeClass someClass;
    @Test 
    public void testAspect() {
        someClass.someMethodCall();
    }
}
```